# Expanding last item of RecyclerView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expand

I have a RecyclerViewAdapter, which implements an expands method in OnClick, but at the last item the expand, doesn't work.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder> {

    private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecylerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Person>  mDataset;
    private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
    private int mExpandedPosition;
    private ViewGroup viewGroup;

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView label;
        TextView dateTime;
        LinearLayout txtDetails;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            label = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txtDetails = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetails);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Person> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        
    }

    @Override
    public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);

        viewGroup = parent;

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);

        //Para expandir
        mExpandedPosition = -1;

        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getCompletName());
        holder.dateTime.setText("" + mDataset.get(position).getAge());


        final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
        holder.txtDetails.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
        holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;

              //  TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, new Fade());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    public void addItem(Person dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Add your adapter's code

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Added, can you see now?